# Не работает realtime output через Popen

Tags: python

Если запускать программу через IDE (PyCharm), то все работает прекрасно.
Если запустить через консоль/bat-файл, то просто нет никакого вывода, подозреваю, что нужно как-то правильно  запускать скрипт.

Фрагмент кода

```
def run_command(command):
    filename = 'test.log'
    with io.open(filename, 'wb') as writer, io.open(filename, 'rb', 1) as reader:
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=writer)
        while process.poll() is None:
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Эта функция вызывается через поток:

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    STOP = False
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        global OUTPUT, STOP
        print(235)
        #p = subprocess.Popen("python main.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=2)
        #for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        if(self.name == "run"):
            run_command("./venv/Scripts/python main.py")
        if(self.name == "stop"):
            """Nothing..."""
```

А сам файл запуска:

```
/venv/Scripts/python interface.py
```

Уже перепробовал кучу вариантов, с записью в лог-файл, и кучу примеров реализации realtime вывода, остановился пока на первом.
Опять же повторюсь, код успешно работает через IDE, но работать через бат-файл отказывается.
Ошибок нет, просто нет вывода (

Comment: минимальное изменение, я подозреваю, это использовать полный путь вместо относительного¶ В целом код можно заметно упростить: не нужен цикл `while poll()`, подкласс Thread создаётся не ясно зачем.¶ Рассмотрите вариант, где вы нужную функциональность внутрь функции поместите в вашем main.py и импортируйте модуль и вызывайте функцию из него. Если хотите именно как внешнюю команду Питон код запускать,  то опишите словами подробно что значит "прекрасно работает": вы хотите сохранить вывод внешней команды в файл, так чтобы не блокировать основной поток? (для этого достаточно всего пары вызовов.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Calling a python script with input within a python script using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)